# Does a class which implements an interface's method (without explicitly implementing that interface) extend that specific interface?

Tags: java, interface, integer, implementation, implicit

I am implementing a class to store objects that can be assigned a *double* value. For this reason, I have created a *HasDoubleValue* interface, that contains a single method:

```
public interface HasDoubleValue{
    public double doubleValue();
}
```

My main class is defined as such:

```
Data <O extends HasDoubleValue> {...}
```

Now, when I try to initialize this class to store Integers, I get a "type argument Integer is not within bounds of type-variable O" error, although Integer implements the *doubleValue()* method by default.

I suppose that this happens because Integer does not explicitly implement my HasDoubleValue interface, although it has the method I am looking for. Is this right? What would a natural workaround be?

Comment: In the case, using a DoubleSupplier as a lambda would allow you call it without changing the classes involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is right. Java doesn't use duck-typing as JavaScript or TypeScript.

A solution is to create an adapter class that wraps a Integer, delegates to it, and actually implement the interface.

Or, since inthis case your interface is a functional interface, to use a lambda or a method reference to create an instance of HasDoubleValue from an Integer.

```
public interface HasDoubleValue{
    double doubleValue();
}

final class IntegerHasDoubleValueAdapter implements HasDoubleValue {
    private final Integer i;

    public IntegerHasDoubleValueAdapter(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return i.doubleValue();
    }
}

class Data<O extends HasDoubleValue> {
    void put(O o) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 42;

        Data<IntegerHasDoubleValueAdapter> d1 = new Data<>();
        d1.put(new IntegerHasDoubleValueAdapter(i));

        Data<HasDoubleValue> d2 = new Data<>();
        d2.put(() -> i.doubleValue());

        Data<HasDoubleValue> d3 = new Data<>();
        d3.put(i::doubleValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would this change if, instead of focusing on integers, I would want to allow any type of object into Data, as long as it can be assigned a double value? I am thinking about modifying the adapter class to check if a doubleValue() method is available for that type, but this feels like it would lead into a vicious circle...

Comment: No. You would just create a separate Adapter class for each type that can't implement HasDoubleValue directly, and put instances of any of those adapters into a Data<HasDoubleValue>.